# Simple sql query with multiple tables

Tags: sql, join, multiple-columns

I'm trying to write a simple query but the output is not correct:

Herer my code:

```
SELECT oc_order_product.order_id AS ordernumber, oc_order_product.quantity,
       oc_order_product.model, oc_order_product.name,
       oc_order.shipping_company, oc_order.shipping_firstname,
       oc_order.shipping_lastname, oc_order.shipping_city, oc_product.location
FROM oc_order_product,
     oc_order,
     oc_product
WHERE oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
  AND oc_order.order_status_id = 1
  AND oc_product.location = 1
ORDER BY ordernumber, oc_order_product.model
```

The output is a list of all products with the oc_order.order_status_id = 1 but the second AND (oc_product.location = 1) is not applied. What is wrong? I don't work with JOIN because I don't understand it really good.

Comment: Tip of today: switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Please start using the modern join syntax http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: You need one more join condition, on oc_product.

Comment: Figure out how to use `JOIN`.  Then you can figure out what is wrong with your query really easily.  If you don't understand `JOIN`, then you don't understand SQL and your queries are just shots in the dark.

Comment: If you don't understand `JOIN`, I suggest you don't touch the database.  You don't want to wipe out your table.

Answer (score 0):

Now using modern, explicit `JOIN`:

```
SELECT oc_order_product.order_id AS ordernumber, oc_order_product.quantity,
       oc_order_product.model, oc_order_product.name,
       oc_order.shipping_company, oc_order.shipping_firstname,
       oc_order.shipping_lastname, oc_order.shipping_city, oc_product.location
FROM oc_order_product
    INNER JOIN oc_order ON oc_order.order_id = oc_order_product.order_id
    INNER JOIN oc_product ON oc_product.id = oc_order_product.product_id
WHERE oc_order.order_status_id = 1
  AND oc_product.location = 1
ORDER BY ordernumber, oc_order_product.model
```

That last join

```
INNER JOIN oc_product ON oc_product.id = oc_order_product.product_id
```

is just a guess, since I don't know which columns to use!

Answer (score 0):

jarlh is guessing that `oc_product.id = oc_order_product.product_id`.

I'm going to guess that your data element names are consistently and uniquely named throughout your schema and therefore suggest you use ultra-modern `NATURAL JOIN`:

```
  SELECT order_id AS ordernumber, quantity,
         model, name, shipping_company, shipping_firstname,
         shipping_lastname, shipping_city, location
    FROM oc_order_product
         NATURAL JOIN oc_order
         NATURAL JOIN oc_product
   WHERE order_status_id = 1
         AND location = 1
   ORDER 
      BY ordernumber, model;
```

...not betting the farm on it, though.